# Can I get back my code changes after hg update removed them?

Tags: mercurial

I am new to Mercurial. I had made some some changes in the code in some of the files and i hadn't committed them yet. but when I did `hg update -c <branch-name>`, all my code changes were gone. Is there any way I can get my code changes back or am I screwed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you perhaps using a very, very, old version of Mercurial?

The help for `hg update` shows that `-c` won't discard uncommitted changes:

```
 -C --clean     discard uncommitted changes (no backup)
 -c --check     update across branches if no uncommitted changes
```

That's been the case for at least four years.  If you try to update to a revision that would discard your local changes Mercurial warns you:

```
ry4an@four:~/test$ hg checkout 0
abort: uncommitted changes
(commit or update --clean to discard changes)
```

If you used `-c` it should have done nothing.  If you used `-C` you should find whomever suggested you do so and yell at them.

Sorry for your loss. :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, as explained in the update help (`hg help update`), --clean don't create backup.

Check if you can get the old version of your files with your text editor with `CTRL + Z`, it already saved my life.

Comment: `CTRL + Z` isn't working for me. This is going to be a lousy weekend.